AfterEffects camera
Very new to Blender.If I've imported a 3D camera and solids from an AfterEffects project (3d camera tracker), how do I align things I build in Blender to those camera/solids? For example, I have a drone shot of a park - camera tracked it in AE... bring that camera into Blender and want to put crowd simulation in the park. When I make a plane or a crowd they come in aligned to the world, so how to I align them to the perspective of the imported camera and solids that mark the ground?
thanks in advance for any help
K

Hello, please provide screenshots of your work/your file. :)

Welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "this","issue with" or "question about". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See "What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"
